# fetch form contact details from my website into whatsapp message space

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

Am creating ecommerce site where user/customers after viewing and ordering the product, message to vendor will go by linking with whatsapp. So for the vendor to deliver the product he/she need to know the address of the customer, there is where I have created a form for contact details for customer to fill in. Now I want after the customer click to link with whatsapp, contact details should appear there in whatsapp. I have gone through [link][1] which describe for only short pre-filled message, now I want the whole contact form details.

Below is the link to whatsapp with the pre-filled message as "Your eshopsy order is:", so instead of the quoted text I want detail from the contact form

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><a href="https://wa.me/255629102101?text=Your%20order%20from%20eshopsy%20vendor%20is:" style="text-decoration:none; color: black; align-content: center;">Click to whatsapp</a>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>
```

Comment: So...just put all the details into the URL parameter as shown in that link. Where **exactly** are you stuck? Did you try? Was there a specific problem?

Comment: I have edited the question, please check above

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to generate a URL string built from the relevant bits of your form fields, and then use window.location to navigate the browser to it. Forget about having a static href value in a link. (You can trigger the javascript from the click of a button of course - or even a link, but just don't give the link a predefined URL).